# how to skip a specific char in string(encrypted in a certain manner) message while printing the message in a specific format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a certain encrypted message which has information about the location(area, city), the characters are jumbled such that first character of the first word is followed by the first character of the second word, then it is followed by the second character of the first word and so on

In other words, let’s say the location is bandra,mumbai

The encrypted message says `‘bmaunmdbraai’`.

Sample Input:

`bmaunmdbraai`

Sample Output:

`bandra,mumbai`

Let’s say the size or length of the two words wouldn’t match then the smaller word is appended with # and then encrypted in the above format.

With this in mind write a code to identify the right location and print it as place,city.

```
input_str='dmeulmhbia#i'
message1=input_str[0::2]
message2=input_str[1::2]
print(message1+","+message2)
```

Comment: Perhaps you just want `input_str[0::2].rstrip("#")`?

Comment: Hi Prateek, welcome to SO! Please consider reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next question.

Answer (score 2):

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
message1 = input_str[0:-1:2]
message2 = input_str[1:len(input_str):2]
print(message1.strip('#') + "," + message2.strip('#'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `[::2]`, you can get every second character. Then just use `rstrip('#')` to remove the unwanted hashtag.

```
input_str='dmeulmhbia#i'

', '.join([input_str[::2].rstrip('#'), input_str[1::2].rstrip('#')])
```

```
Out[5]: 'bandra, mumbai'
```

Separated by `', '`, I am concatenating every second letter, and also every second letter starting from the second letter, and remove `#` when it's detected at the end of either word.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_str='dmeulmhbia#i'
message1=input_str[0::2].rstrip('#')
message2=input_str[1::2].rstrip('#')
print(message1+","+message2)
```

Comment: @J.C Thanks for your effort on editing the formatting here. But it teaches the wrong lesson that only the formatting is a problem in this answer....

Comment: Raghul Srinivas, please make the addtional insight more obvious which this answer provides in comparison to the functionally identical upvoted answer by Akshay Sharma. Generally, answer are better with an explanation of how the shown code works and why it helps to solve the problem. The shown code gives the impression of a thinly veiled copy of other users contribution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, you may use a loop to resolve the same.

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
city=''
place=''
len_name=len(input_str)
for i in range(0,len_name) :
    if i%2==0 :
     city=city+input_str[i]
    else :
    `place=place+input_str[i]
message1=city.rstrip('#')
message2=place.rstrip('#')
print(message1+","+message2)
```